# ERROR --> java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 21

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to execute a query in java code, the query is:

```
SELECT *FROM(
SELECT p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION
FROM  EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT p, EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD, PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
WHERE p.status = 1
AND p.transfersequence IN(?)
AND p.sirano =?
AND p.paymentstatus IN(?)
AND P.CORPORATION = SOD.INNOVACODE
AND P.SERVICEINFO = SD.SUBSCRIBERNO
AND SD.CORPORATECODE = SOD.CODE
AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN('22')
AND SD.STATUS = 1
AND P.DUEDATE =?
AND P.CORPORATION NOT IN('10000','203','500','501','405','213')
UNION ALL SELECT p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION
FROM EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT p, EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD, PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
WHERE p.status = 1
AND p.transfersequence IN(?)
AND p.sirano =?
AND p.paymentstatus IN(?)
AND P.CORPORATION = SOD.INNOVACODE
AND P.SERVICEINFO = SD.SUBSCRIBERNO2 || SD.SUBSCRIBERNO
AND SD.CORPORATECODE = SOD.CODE
AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN('22')
AND SD.STATUS = 1
AND P.DUEDATE =?
AND P.CORPORATION IN('203','213','221')
UNION ALL SELECT p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION
FROM EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT p, EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD, PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
WHERE p.status = 1
AND p.transfersequence IN(?)
AND p.sirano =?
AND p.paymentstatus IN(?)
AND P.CORPORATION = SOD.INNOVACODE
AND P.SERVICEINFO = SD.SUBSCRIBERNO
AND P.CORPACCOUNTID = SD.CORPACCOUNTID
AND SD.CORPORATECODE = SOD.CODE
AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN('22')
AND SD.STATUS = 1
AND P.DUEDATE =?
AND P.CORPORATION IN('500','501')
UNION ALL SELECT p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION
FROM EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT p, EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD, PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
WHERE p.status = 1
AND p.transfersequence IN(?)
AND p.sirano =?
AND p.paymentstatus IN(?)
AND P.CORPORATION = SOD.INNOVACODE
AND P.SERVICEINFO = SD.SUBSCRIBERNO
AND P.SERVICEINFO2 = TO_NUMBER( SD.SUBSCRIBERNO2 )
AND SD.CORPORATECODE = SOD.CODE
AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN('22')
AND SD.STATUS = 1
AND P.DUEDATE =?
AND P.CORPORATION IN('405')
AND SD.CORPORATECODE = '405'
UNION ALL SELECT p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION
FROM ( SELECT iso.* 
FROM EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT iso
WHERE iso.CORPORATION IN('10000')
ORDER BY iso.billnumber ) p, EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD, PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
WHERE p.status = 1
AND p.transfersequence IN(?)
AND p.sirano =?
AND p.paymentstatus IN(?)
AND P.CORPORATION = SOD.INNOVACODE
AND P.SERVICEINFO = SD.SUBSCRIBERNO
AND P.SERVICEINFO2 = TO_NUMBER( SD.SUBSCRIBERNO2 )
AND SD.CORPORATECODE = SOD.CODE
AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN('22')
AND SD.STATUS = 1
AND P.DUEDATE =?
AND P.CORPORATION IN('10000') ) q
```

When I try to execute this query in SQL Developer it works fine, but in jdbc it is throwing an exception.
java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 21

the java code is:

```
            qe = new CBQueryExecuter("EXT_GET_INNOVA_SO_DETAIL_BY_OID");
            qe.setParameter("TRNSEQ"       , headerID.split(","));
            qe.setParameter("SIRANO"    , bchOrderNo);
            qe.setParameter("PYTSTATUS"    , pytStatus);
            qe.setParameter("DATE"      , inBag.get(DATENUMBER).toString());

            qe.setParameter("TRNSEQ2"       , headerID.split(","));
            qe.setParameter("SIRANO2"    , bchOrderNo);
            qe.setParameter("PYTSTATUS2"    , pytStatus);
            qe.setParameter("DATE2"      , inBag.get(DATENUMBER).toString());


            qe.setParameter("TRNSEQ3"       , headerID.split(","));
            qe.setParameter("SIRANO3"    , bchOrderNo);
            qe.setParameter("PYTSTATUS3"    , pytStatus);
            qe.setParameter("DATE3"      , inBag.get(DATENUMBER).toString());


            qe.setParameter("TRNSEQ4"       , headerID.split(","));
            qe.setParameter("SIRANO4"    , bchOrderNo);
            qe.setParameter("PYTSTATUS4"    , pytStatus);
            qe.setParameter("DATE4"      , inBag.get(DATENUMBER).toString());

            qe.executeQuery();

            while (qe.next()) {

                transferSequence = qe.getString("TRANSFERSEQUENCE");

                accountOID = qe.getLong("ACCOUNTOID");

                //accountNr = qe.getString("ACCOUNTNO").toString();

                if (accountOID!=0) {

                    accBag.clear();
                    accBag.put(ACCOUNTOID , accountOID) ;
                    accBag = CBCaller.call("HESAP_HESAPBILGILERIGETIR", accBag); 

                    accountNr = accBag.get(ACCOUNTNR).toString();

                    CBSessionInfo.setIslemAnaBirimKodu(accBag.get(BRANCHCODE).toString());

                }
```

Query works fine without union all at the end of the query.

```
UNION ALL SELECT p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION
FROM ( SELECT iso.* 
FROM EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT iso
WHERE iso.CORPORATION IN('10000')
ORDER BY iso.billnumber ) p, EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD, PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
WHERE p.status = 1
AND p.transfersequence IN(?)
AND p.sirano =?
AND p.paymentstatus IN(?)
AND P.CORPORATION = SOD.INNOVACODE
AND P.SERVICEINFO = SD.SUBSCRIBERNO
AND P.SERVICEINFO2 = TO_NUMBER( SD.SUBSCRIBERNO2 )
AND SD.CORPORATECODE = SOD.CODE
AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN('22')
AND SD.STATUS = 1
AND P.DUEDATE =?
AND P.CORPORATION IN('10000')
```

Although i think my code is correct but then also it is showing error,So please tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: Show the java too

Comment: ps; IN(?) looks suspect to me, but I'm mainly C# - we do not parameterize IN that way, we have to add as many parameters as there are things in the list for the IN. Are you successfully passing more than one value to it (perhaps [like this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbctemplate-in-list)) or is it a potential source of problem?

Comment: Doesn't get inside the while loop

Comment: Ok. Show the java too

Comment: I added to the question

Comment: Check with the split call, if its returning a string then okay, but if its returning an array then this would not set dynamic values with one single ? placeholder

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is with the ```IN(?)``` . A bind variable is a single variable - a comma separated list cannot be treated as a single bind variable. Google "oracle bind variable comma separated list" to get you going.
As for debugging... well we all need to do it, it is a very useful skill. Reduce the complexity of your code, start with a single bind. add code, run, fix, repeat.

Comment: Btw, prefer using explicit `JOIN` keywords as being easy to read and use especially for the cases whenever `OUTER JOIN`s are needed rather than comma-seperated-table joins.

Comment: Query works fine without union all at the end of the query. If it's like you said, it should have failed for other IN (?) s too, right?